# Why is object initialization different inside a struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, initialization, member-initialization

I have created a class Point, here is the corresponding hpp file.

```
#ifndef POINT
#define POINT
class Point
{
 protected:
 int x;
 int y;
 public:
 Point(int x = 10, int y = 10);
 void movePoint(int moveX, int moveY);
 void printCoordinates();
};
#endif
```

I noticed that in the main, I can declare an object and initialize it this way:

```
Point myPoint(1, 1);
```

If I want to create a structure containing two points, it won't let me initialize it this way, instead, I have to use curly brackets, this way:

```
struct segment
{
 Point point1 = {0, 0};
 Point point2 = {15, 15};
};
```

Why is that?

Comment: imagine asking the compiler to parse `int x(n);` inside `template<typename B> class S : public B` where it is not known whether `n` is an `int`, or a typename from `B`

Answer (score 6):

Because [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11) only supports equal-sign initializer and braced initializer.

(emphasis mine)

> Through a *default member initializer*, which is **a brace or equals initializer** included in the member declaration and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.

So you can

```
struct segment
{
 Point point1 = {0, 0};        // equal-sign initializer
 Point point2 = Point(15, 15); // equal-sign initializer
 Point point3 = Point{30, 30}; // equal-sign initializer
 Point point4 {45, 45};        // braced initializer
};
```

`Point myPoint(1, 1);` as default member initializer might cause ambiguity trouble with function declaration.

Comment: More emphasis should be put on the ambiguity with function declaration here. It's actually the core reason why it's not allowed.